# I want to create custom cursor in canvas drawing in angular7

Tags: typescript, canvas, angular7

I want to create custom cursor in canvas drawing.
My code is following below-- where 'assets/image/edit.svg' is the image path which i want to show as a cursor.
 this.canvas.freeDrawingCursor='url(assets/image/edit.svg), auto';

But its not happening.

Comment: Can you provide your full code example?

Comment: ngOnInit() {   
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      hoverCursor: 'pointer',
      selection: true,
      selectionBorderColor: 'blue'
    });

}//end of oninit

Then I have created a method where i want to create custom cursor and calling it on my html button click.
pencil() {
    this.canvas.freeDrawingCursor='url(assets/image/edit.svg), auto'; 
    this.canvas.isDrawingMode = 1;
    this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 10;
    this.canvas.renderAll();
  }